# jqGrid fetched json but has empty rows and no data

Tags: jquery, json, model-view-controller, spring, jqgrid

> JSON As generated by Spring 3 MVC
>   @ResponseBody

```
{
    "total": "1",
    "page": "1",
    "records": "2",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cell": {
                "accountId": 1,
                "userId": 1,
                "transactionId": 6,
                "subCatId": 0,
                "accountName": "Credit Card",
                "remarks": "Movie Hall Pass",
                "amount": 250.0,
                "transactionDate": "2011-03-16",
                "subCatName": "Entertainment"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "cell": {
                "accountId": 2,
                "userId": 1,
                "transactionId": 7,
                "subCatId": 1,
                "accountName": "Savings Bank",
                "remarks": "Part at Besand Nagar",
                "amount": 5000.0,
                "transactionDate": "2011-03-16",
                "subCatName": "Dine Out"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> JQGrid Initialization Code:

```
$("#transactionLogTable").jqGrid({
                url: '/et/transaction/getTransactions?dateValue=03%2F16%2F2011',
                datatype: "json",
                loadError: function(xhr,status,error){alert(status+" "+error);},
                colNames:['Transaction ID', 'User ID', 'Subcat ID', 'Subcat Name',
                          'Account ID', 'Account Name', 'Date', 'Amount', 'Notes'],

                colModel:[
                    {name: 'transactionId', index: 'transactionId', width: 100},
                    {name: 'userid', index: 'userId', width: 100},
                    {name: 'subCatId', index: 'subCatId', width: 100},
                    {name: 'subCatName', index: 'subCatName', width: 100},
                    {name: 'accountId', index: 'accountId', width: 100},
                    {name: 'accountName', index: 'accountName', width: 100},
                    {name: 'transactionDate', index: 'transactionDate', width: 100},
                    {name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 100},
                    {name: 'remarks', index: 'remarks', width: 100}
                ],
                pager: "#pager",
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10,20,30],
                sortname: 'userId',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: 'Transactions'
            });
```

The server is been hit successfully with QueryString as:

```
dateValue=03%2F16%2F2011&_search=false&nd=1300532086871&rows=10&page=1&sidx=userId&sord=asc
```

Fine now, I get a screen which has the jqGrid displayed and 2 empty rows in it. I can't get to display the data inside the rows.

I guess it's something related to the mapping, but I have tried as many combinations I can.

Included files and versions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/et/resources/js/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2.full/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/et/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.start/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/et/resources/js/form-2.52.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/et/resources/js/validate-1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/et/resources/js/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2.full/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/et/resources/js/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2.full/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

Appreciate your help.

Firdous Amir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main error is that the data are wrong formatted. You should use

```
{
    "total": "1",
    "page": "1",
    "records": "2",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cell": ["1", "1", "6", "0", "Credit Card", "Movie Hall Pass",
                     "250.0", "2011-03-16", "Entertainment" ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "total": "1",
    "page": "1",
    "records": "2",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cell": {
                "accountId": 1,
                "userId": 1,
                "transactionId": 6,
                "subCatId": 0,
                "accountName": "Credit Card",
                "remarks": "Movie Hall Pass",
                "amount": 250.0,
                "transactionDate": "2011-03-16",
                "subCatName": "Entertainment"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

In general jqGrid is flexible enough to read almost any JSON data. You can just define the [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) jqGrid parameter and sometime additionally `jsonmap` property in the column definition. In your case for example one can read your data with the following jqGrid definition

```
$("#transactionLogTable").jqGrid({
    // ... other parameters
    cmTemplate: {width: 100},
    colModel:[
        {name:'transactionId',   jsonmap: 'cell.transactionId'},
        {name:'userId',          jsonmap: 'cell.userId'},
        {name:'subCatId',        jsonmap: 'cell.subCatId'},
        {name:'subCatName',      jsonmap: 'cell.subCatName'},
        {name:'accountId',       jsonmap: 'cell.accountId'},
        {name:'accountName',     jsonmap: 'cell.accountName'},
        {name:'transactionDate', jsonmap: 'cell.transactionDate'},
        {name:'amount',          jsonmap: 'cell.amount'},
        {name:'remarks',         jsonmap: 'cell.remarks'}
    ],
    height: "auto",
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }
});
```

Here I used `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` to define that JSON data for a row are not in array for, but in for of object with named property. The property like `jsonmap: "cell.userId"` is needed to specify that the value for the corresponding grid column should be not as the default `userId` property of the row object, but are additionally are the child of the "cell" property. By the way you use 'userid' as the column name and 'userId' in the JSON data. It is better to use the same names as the JSON data. In you use the same 'index' property as the 'name' you can drop out the 'index'. In the case the value of the 'name' property will be used as the 'index'.

Because you used "width:100" property for all columns of your grid I used `cmTemplate: {width: 100}` parameter to make `colModel` definition shorter and better to read.

You can see the modified grid live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user667200.htm).

I recommend you additionally post the date always in the ISO form YYYY-mm-dd and use [formatter:'date'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) and [datefmt](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) properties of `colModel` (for example `formatter:'date', formatoptions:{newformat:'d-m-Y'}, datefmt: 'd-m-Y'`)

Comment: Thank you @Oleg ! That fixed the problem. I was merely following the jqGrid documentation and I was never able to find what you have just explained. This is my first attempt with jqGrid and I prefer this more than DataTables. Thanks again !

Comment: @firdousamir: You are welcome! What do you can't find in the documenation? Date format, `jsonReader`, `jsonmap`, `cmTemplate` or some more... If you stay have some problem I could try to explain you some things or post you urls with examples.

Comment: Your answer pretty much indeed gets be a better clarity regarding the usage. I'm learning/experimenting with the grid and spring 3 as part of my new project. I get more confidence now as a you are there for help.

Comment: @firdousamir: To be able to help you I need to have **specific questions** from you where you explain what exactly you not understand and where I could help you. You can just compare your code with my code from http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user667200.htm. You can additionally change your server code to produce JSON like default input format described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data). Then you will not need any `jsonReader` or `jsonmap`.